# Simple ifstream not opening any file

Tags: c++, ifstream

Newb here. I have spent the last 4 hours trying to solve this problem.

ifstream is suddenly not opening files.
ofstream has no problems writing to the file.

The file exists, it's contents are, `ThisIsText`, and it is in the reference directory, which I confirmed with system("dir & pause")

I tried Code::Blocks and Dev C++, but I think they're using the same compiler(GNU GCC Compiler).
I tried using the full filename path with double backslashes.
I see people mentioning permissions, but I don't know how to tinker with that.
I'm on Windows 10.

Edit: I just found a new compiler(Embarcadero 10.1 AKA Borland) and the code works with it. I still want to know what the problem is with GNU GCC

The following code skips to the else statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string message;
    ifstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("File.txt");

    if (inputFile.good())
    {
        inputFile >> message;
        cout << message;
        system("dir & pause");

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "failed to open input file\n";
        system("dir & pause");
    }   return 0;
}
```

If it helps, I found the following code online and it outputs, "Error code = 2"
from winerror.h, that is: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
    "one.txt", // Windows does not case about case
    GENERIC_READ,
    0, // no sharing
    NULL, // default security
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL ); // no file template

  if(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFile)
  {
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError(); // see winerror.h for meanings
    std::cout << "File wouldn't open :-(" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Error code = " << errCode << std::endl;
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "File opened OK :-)" << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

PS. I know `using namespace std;` is bad practice

Comment: Try giving an absolute path to it. Otherwise there is nothing here that would indicate an issue. Also, use a `std::endl` in your `cout` statements to make sure the buffer is flushed (for debugging only)

Comment: Is there an `error` produced by YOUR code? or just revert to the `else` block?

Comment: are you using some IDE?

Comment: Where is the file?

Comment: It works with a different compiler.

Comment: As stated in the original post, 
@AndyG: absolute path doesn't work,
@Duly Kinsky: Code::Blocks,
 @immibis: It is in the same directory as the exe,
@m_callens: No compiler error, just the `failed to open input file` statement from the code. I should have specified.